# Delphi 7 Soap WCF Service using basicHttpBinding

Tags: delphi, wsdl, wcf, delphi-7, basichttpbinding

I added a basicHttpBinding to an existing Service I have in production in order to expose it for use in Delphi.

When I try to use the WSDLImporter from Delphi 7 on the wsdl file, it doesn't work right.

A section in the resulting tlb says

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
// in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
// to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
// typically map to predefined/known XML or Borland types; however, they could also
// indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
// ************************************************************************ //
```

This service is consumed fine by .NET client.  The service is using complexTypes but they are in the files and they are the newer split out to multiple files for imports by xsd.

Any way of doing this in Delphi 7?  I even tried pulling all imported types back to 1 wsdl document.  No difference.

Thanks, 
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old (very) but it might help someone else out struggling through this like we were with WCF interoperability with Delphi.

What made the difference in my own experience was

1. using basicHttpBinding
2. using the Delphi wsdlImp command line tool
3. enforcing Soap 1.1
4. pointing to the SingleWsdl address.

Here is an what our WsdlImp command looks like:

```
wsdlimp  -P -XName -Ox- -SOAP11 -Oa- -Ol+ -ob+ -= http://srvAddress:1253/WCF.Server/Utils.svc/metadata?singleWsdl=UtilsWsdl.pas
```

Comment: I am accepting this... I will assume it works.  I am no longer working with Delphi.

Comment: Which version of wsdlimp support -SOAP11 option? (version 11.0.2811.27992 does not support)

Comment: based on Jeroen's answer, you can leave this parameter out since it will already be Soap11.

Comment: how to pass login and password for web service?

Comment: -user:UserName - pass:Password, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/WSDLIMP.EXE,_the_Command_Line_WSDL_Import_Tool

Answer (score 0):

First guess is that the WCF service is SOAP 1.2, for which support was added in Delphi 2010.

For Delphi 7, you could try some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393727/how-is-the-best-way-to-write-a-soap-1-2-client-with-delphi-win32).

--jeroen

Comment: i see... Well it took them long enough.   Thanks.

Comment: basicHttpBinding is the very basic binding - SOAP 1.1, not much in terms of security, not much else in terms of features - but compatible to just about any SOAP client out there --> great for interoperability, weak on features and security