# Call Web Service and Return Error in Delphi 7

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl, delphi-7, delphi-xe5

I have import a WSDL in **Delphi 7** and Call a function on it and an error message will be displayed:

*Project Project1.exe raised exception class ERemotableException with message 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.*

[image]

When I call WebService method (**in Delphi 7**), with Fiddler software I got the message contents(XML) posted :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><NS1:Save xmlns:NS1="http://tempuri.org/"><from xsi:type="xsd:string">1</from><to xsi:type="xsd:string">2</to><body xsi:type="xsd:string">ServiceTest</body></NS1:Save></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

[image]

And then I call the same method and web service in **Delphi XE5** with no error and this XML content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Body><Save xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><from>1</from><to>2</to><body>ServiceTest</body></Save></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

SOAP Server Response :
[image]

*SOAP Web Service write in .NET framework and support SOAP 1.1 and 1.2*

Any ideas?

Comment: Delphi 7 is old, so why you want to use the wizard from that version?

Comment: Have you applied the [Delphi SOAP Runtime and Importer Update](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/24535)?

Comment: @mjn , I've installed the update but again the same error displayed

Comment: Can you format the XML request examples to make it easier to see the small differences in them?

Comment: @whosrdaddy , This is a big and old project and I have no other choice.

Comment: Can you also capture the server response  (the one which contains the SOAP fault xml element)? Maybe it contains any additional helpful information which is not being displayed in the error dialog.

Comment: If everything fails you could try the Free Pascal Web Services Toolkit. It claims to be Delphi compatible and includes a WSDL importer. The generated source code however looks different. Also I would confirm that the Delphi request is malformed by pasting it in a SoapUI test request body.

Comment: AFAIR Delphi 7 supports only SOAP 1.1. Try to follow the steps available at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19023959/458259

Comment: thanks @ArnaudBouchez, I have test wsdlimp(with new update) and does not support -SOAP11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use THTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute for change SOAPResponse.Then delete unnecessary attribute and type in XML source and packing again and assign it to SOAPResponse and send it.

In this method the problem was solved.